# Physical limit for python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is the number of python multiprocessing limited by the physical specifications of a pc, i.e. the number of physical cores and logical processors? For example, my PC has 12 cores and 24 logical processor and if I run say 14 multiprocessing simultaneously, is it fine since I have 24 logical processor, or it is actually not running 14 multiprocessing since I only have 12 cores?

I googled but there is no exact answer to my question.

Comment: If your processor has **x** cores, then only **x** threads will run at a time. The operating system handles rapidly switching between all the threads so that many many more can exist, but only so many will actually be running at a time.

Comment: Logical vs physical cores is more cpu and workload specific. You may not benefit using any more processes than the number of physical cores, or you may benefit using up to the number of logical cores. You will have to test yourself for your own application.